# Neither of my original list and my filtered list is deleted after entering search query

Tags: java, android

I have two arraylist here, soilList where it contains data about soil and filteredList which is used for the search. When a user enters a search query, filter() method is called to filter the list of soil items based on the entered text. The program also have two delete button. One button is for clearing all the soilList,  which is working fine. The other button (called TextView delete) which is for deleting an individual item is not doing its job. When deleting an item from soilList in adapter, it doesn't affect the filtered list (filteredList) in  main activity, causing the deleted item to reappear when performing a search again, I think.

MAIN CLASS

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ListSoil> soilList;
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    ImageView deleteAll;
    AlertDialog.Builder deleteAllBuilder;
    EditText searchHx;
    ArrayList<ListSoil> filteredList;

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addList();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        initRecyclerView();

        deleteAll = findViewById(R.id.deleteAll);
        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        deleteAllBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        deleteAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                deleteAllBuilder.setTitle("Alert").setMessage("Do you want to delete all?").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        soilList.clear();
                        filteredList.clear();
                        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Items deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });

        searchHx = findViewById(R.id.searchHx);
        //searchHx.clearFocus();
        searchHx.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.numbers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListSoil item: soilList) {
            if (item.getSoilName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addList() {
        soilList = new ArrayList<>();
        soilList.add(new ListSoil("Soil 1", "Passed", "date",0, 0, 0));
        soilList.add(new ListSoil("Soil 2", "Failed", "date",0, 0, 0));
        soilList.add(new ListSoil("Soil 3", "Passed", "date",0, 0, 0));
        soilList.add(new ListSoil("Soil 4", "Passed","date",0, 0, 0));
        soilList.add(new ListSoil("Soil 5", "Passed", "date",0, 0, 10));
    }
    private void initRecyclerView(){
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(soilList, filteredList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*if (text.equals("Ascending")) {
        } else if (text.equals("Descending")) {
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

ADAPTER CLASS

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<ListSoil> soilList;
    AlertDialog.Builder deleteBuilder;
    ArrayList<ListSoil> filteredList;
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<ListSoil> soilList,ArrayList<ListSoil> filteredList) {
        this.soilList = soilList;
        this.filteredList = filteredList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListSoil list = soilList.get(position);
        holder.soilName.setText(list.getSoilName());
        holder.remarks.setText(list.getRemarks());
        holder.date.setText(list.getDate());
        holder.nitrogenInput.setText(String.valueOf(list.getNitrogenInput()));
        holder.phosphorusInput.setText(String.valueOf(list.getPhosphorusInput()));
        holder.potassiumInput.setText(String.valueOf(list.getPotassiumInput()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return soilList.size();
    }
    public void filterList(ArrayList<ListSoil> filteredList) {
        soilList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView soilName, remarks, date, nitrogenInput, phosphorusInput, potassiumInput, delete;
        ConstraintLayout expandableLayout;
        ImageView arrow;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            soilName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.soilName);
            remarks = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remarks);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            nitrogenInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nitrogenInput);
            phosphorusInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phosphorusInput);
            potassiumInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.potassiumInput);
            expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
            arrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (expandableLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
                    } else {
                        expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
                    }
                }
            });
            deleteBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.getContext());
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    deleteBuilder.setTitle("Alert")
                            .setMessage("Do you want to delete this?")
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    soilList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                                    if (filteredList != null) {
                                        filteredList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                                    }
                                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

LIST CLASS

```
public class ListSoil {
    String soilName;
    String remarks;
    String date;
    int nitrogenInput;
    int phosphorusInput;
    int potassiumInput;

    public ListSoil(String soilName, String remarks, String date, int nitrogenInput, int phosphorusInput, int potassiumInput) {
        this.soilName = soilName;
        this.remarks = remarks;
        this.date = date;
        this.nitrogenInput = nitrogenInput;
        this.phosphorusInput = phosphorusInput;
        this.potassiumInput = potassiumInput;
    }

    public String getSoilName() {
        return soilName;
    }

    public void setSoilName(String soilName) {
        this.soilName = soilName;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getNitrogenInput() {
        return nitrogenInput;
    }

    public void setNitrogenInput(int nitrogenInput) {
        this.nitrogenInput = nitrogenInput;
    }

    public int getPhosphorusInput() {
        return phosphorusInput;
    }

    public void setPhosphorusInput(int phosphorusInput) {
        this.phosphorusInput = phosphorusInput;
    }

    public int getPotassiumInput() {
        return potassiumInput;
    }

    public void setPotassiumInput(int potassiumInput) {
        this.potassiumInput = potassiumInput;
    }
}
```

idk how to delete an item in filteredList

Comment: i belive that you remove it but in the recyclerview but not showing in main activity ... any way lets solve it directly .. the best solution it to use interface with RecyclerAdapter and remove it from the list of MainActivity.class ---- snippet RecyclerAdapter ( interface OnItemDeleteClickListener - OnItemDeleteClickListener onItemDeleteClickListener - setOnItemDeleteClickListener(OnItemDeleteClickListener DeleteItem) ) (recyclerAdapter.setOnItemDeleteClickListener(new RecyclerAdapter.OnItemDeleteClickListener()){ the implementation code remove here from the list and refresh the RV }